# Stack overflow Exception C++ Visual 2010 Open file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stack-overflow, unhandled-exception

I've opened a text file in Visual Studio 2010, with **size 500 MB (8 million line)** and read it without problems.

But when I tried to open another file with **size  54 MB (2.5 million line)**, its failed and give a ***stack overflow exception***!

Why this although file 2 is smaller? 
EDIT:

```
void main()
{
   string line;
   ifstream inputfile1;
   inputfile1.open("file1.txt");

   while(!inputfile1.eof())
   {
       getline(inputfile1,line);
   }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what it is you're doing.  Are you starting Visual Studio, then going to the main menu and opening a file?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've edited the question for clarity

Comment: `!inputfile1.eof()` -- [Please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks, but the exception happened when executing the statement ifstream inputfile1 during debugging, i.e. before use eof()

Comment: If you fail to open the file, the loop will never terminate.

Comment: I move the code to another new project and works fine! although I didn't change any configuration in the old project!